# override size property of a control does not expand with height and width

Tags: c#, properties, size, controls, propertygrid

The custom size property first shows with a `'+"` sign on load into the propertygrid, But When I click the `'+'` sign to expand it to view height and width, I do not see Height and width.
I've used the below code to code my custom Size

```
[Browsable(true),Category("Properties")]
[DefaultValue(typeof(Size), "150,25")]
public new Size Size
{
    get { return SDLabelSize; }
    set { SDLabelSize = value; this.ClientSize = value; }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that, works just fine when I try it.  Impossible to guess what might be going wrong without a small repro.

Comment: I've used the below to pull the properties              propertyGrid.BrowsableAttributes = new AttributeCollection(new CategoryAttribute("Properties")); If I comment the above Size is working fine showing Height and Width...Any Clues??